# Datatables Filter + stateSave

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable that has a link to a CRUD updater. Once the user submits changes I am returning them to the table and using the `stateSave: true` option to keep the state of the datatable. This is all working.

I also have a custom filter box. What happens is when the user submits a change the table refreshes and restores to the saved state, however the filter box doesn't show the filter the user inputed it only shows the placeholder. How do I reload the filter variable back into the filter input box?

Thanks!

Edit: [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/po5vy7od/)

**Note**: 1) Run the JSFiddle and filter for something. 2) Run the JSFiddle again, it should load your saved state. 3) Note that the input is only in the default datatables filter, not in `id="searchbox"`

JavaScript (Datatable):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        oTable = $('#dataTables').dataTable( {
        "sDom": '<"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">', 
        fnDrawCallback : function() {
        $('#dataTables').highlight(['Empty']);
        },  
    stateSave: true
    });
    $('#searchbox').on("input", function() {
     oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() );
    });
    $('#searchbtn').click(function(){
     oTable.fnFilter( $(searchbox).val() );
    });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML (Input Group):

```
<div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search" id="searchbox">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="searchbtn" type="button">Search</button>
    </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

**Edit:**
For reference, I enabled the default DOM filter element just to see what it was doing on a reload of saved state. The filter is still there in the default filter box but not in my custom one. I need to get the filter input into the top filter box.

[image: Custom filter (top), default filter (bottom)]

Comment: I think you can use [fnStateLoadParams](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnStateLoadParams) for this

Comment: @markpsmith Looking at that function now. Added a screenshot of what is happening. Thanks.